# Como configuro un evento predeterminado de un control dentro de un UserControl vb.net

Tags: vb.net, eventos

Cree un User control al cual agregue algunos controles, por ejemplo un combo box un label y algunas otras cosas.

Al agregar mi usercontrol a un form y acceder al evento predeterminado siempre sale el load de mi control de usuario; sin embargo, quiero que al acceder al evento predeterminado sea el
SelectedIndexChanged de mi combobox

**Ejemplo tengo esta clase userControl a la cual le agrego unos controles**

```
Public Class CyComboBox : Inherits UserControl
    Private ComboBox1 As ComboBox
    Private Label1 As Label
    Private IconButton1 As Button
End Class
```

**Al agregarlo a mi form1 ejemplo todo bien aparece como quiero y todo sin emabrgo al querer acceder a su evento predeterminado siempre me sale el de *usercontrol.Load* y lo que yo necesito es que ese evento apunte al *combobox1.SelectedIdexChange* ya intente colocar el default con la etiqueta, sin embargo, me dice que el evento no es accesible**

[image: UserControl]

Tengo mi usercontrol al cual contiene un combobox un label y un boton,
los cuales ya edite para que tomen forma y colores que yo elegi y hace un cambio de texto al label cada vez que el texto cambie en el combobox

[image: UserControl desde Form1]

Se agrega correctamente y toma la forma y colores bien pero quiero establecer desde form 1 acceso al evento que se genera al momento de cambiar el texto pero solo me aparecen eventos del mismo user control

[image: Al añadir evento desde Form1]

y esto es lo que pasa cuando intento añadir el evento de manera forzada desde form1 y no se como darle acceso

Answer (score 0):

```
<DefaultEvent("OnSelectedIndexChanged")>

Public Class CyComboBox 
    Inherits UserControl

End Class
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).